# Creating feature (row) vectors, for SVM, from Pandas GroupBy function (and or other methods suggested)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to create stacked feature vectors for an SVM classifier. I have all my data in a large matrix. The problem at hand is a multi-class classification problem so I need to group using multi-index.

Here is a toy-example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
N = 4
col_ids = string.letters[:N]
df = pd.DataFrame(
      np.random.randint(10, size=(16,N)),       #np.random.randn(1,N),
      columns=['col_{}'.format(letter) for letter in col_ids])

test_cols = ['test1','test1','test1','test1','test1','test1','test1','test1','test2','test2','test2','test2','test2','test2','test2','test2']
test_iter = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]

df.insert(0, 'Activity', test_cols)
df.insert(1, 'Iteration', test_iter)
```

Output:

```
   Activity  Iteration  col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D
0     test1          1      7      2      9      7
1     test1          1      9      7      2      7
2     test1          1      4      4      2      2
3     test1          1      0      1      0      6
4     test1          2      3      5      3      3
5     test1          2      9      5      7      6
6     test1          2      9      5      8      6
7     test1          2      9      7      9      1
8     test2          1      3      2      5      5
9     test2          1      8      5      9      0
10    test2          1      8      6      3      9
11    test2          1      3      9      2      5
12    test2          2      0      4      4      1
13    test2          2      7      0      4      6
14    test2          2      5      4      0      9
15    test2          2      0      0      5      0
```

I use the following groupby to get the appropriate groups for my application:

```
g = df.groupby(["Activity", "Iteration"])

                      Activity  Iteration  col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D
Activity   Iteration                                                   
test1    1         0     test1          1      7      2      9      7
                   1     test1          1      9      7      2      7
                   2     test1          1      4      4      2      2
                   3     test1          1      0      1      0      6
         2         4     test1          2      3      5      3      3
                   5     test1          2      9      5      7      6
                   6     test1          2      9      5      8      6
                   7     test1          2      9      7      9      1
test2    1         8     test2          1      3      2      5      5
                   9     test2          1      8      5      9      0
                   10    test2          1      8      6      3      9
                   11    test2          1      3      9      2      5
         2         12    test2          2      0      4      4      1
                   13    test2          2      7      0      4      6
                   14    test2          2      5      4      0      9
                   15    test2          2      0      0      5      0
```

Now I would like to create feature vectors and store them into a new DataFrame but in a way that only uses two rows to create one feature vector. Meaning that in the test example the `test1` activity is performed twice with each iteration having the same label so in this case it has two labels: 1 and 2. From each label two rows should be stacked to create the desired output.

From `test1` I would like to create four row vectors, such that complete output (ideally) looks as such:

```
test1 test1 ... test2
    7     4         5
    2     4         4
    9     2         0
    7     2         9
    9     0         0
    7     1         0
    2     0         5
    7     6         9
```

I have not written out the whole thing but I hope it is obvious what I would like to achieve. Basically; two rows become one stacked row vector (with the label on top), the same vector is one feature vector. As I have multiple activities I need multiple feature vectors per activity to train the SVM. For this example I would ideally get one pd.DataFrame with eight feature rows vectors in it so the data frame will have been re-shaped (ignoring everything but the actual data contained in col_A through col_B) from (16,4) to (8,8).

This is not amazingly explained I know, so please let know if you need further details, should you be in the mood to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function to the `groupby` which prepares the data for the final output, and then relabel the columns, just like this:

```
def f(x):
    values = [v for vals in x.values for v in vals[2:]]
    return pd.Series(values,name=x.values[0][0])

res = df.groupby(["Activity", "Iteration"]).apply(f)
res = res.T.rename(columns={(t,i):t for t,i in res.index})
print df   
print res
```

Which in my test outputs: (note that the data is random!)

```
   Activity  Iteration  col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D
0     test1          1      4      6      5      7
1     test1          1      5      9      5      4
2     test1          1      1      8      7      9
3     test1          1      4      8      1      9
4     test1          2      4      5      5      6
5     test1          2      6      3      8      6
6     test1          2      8      1      1      2
7     test1          2      5      1      8      1
8     test2          1      6      3      9      9
9     test2          1      4      9      9      7
10    test2          1      5      0      1      3
11    test2          1      5      8      9      5
12    test2          2      4      8      3      2
13    test2          2      8      9      9      4
14    test2          2      6      1      1      8
15    test2          2      6      4      4      8
    test1  test1  test2  test2
0       4      4      6      4
1       6      5      3      8
2       5      5      9      3
3       7      6      9      2
4       5      6      4      8
5       9      3      9      9
6       5      8      9      9
7       4      6      7      4
8       1      8      5      6
9       8      1      0      1
10      7      1      1      1
11      9      2      3      8
12      4      5      5      6
13      8      1      8      4
14      1      8      9      4
15      9      1      5      8
```

2 columns of 8 elements on each test is a little more tricky but you can do this the same way:

```
def g(x):
    values = [v for vals in x.values for v in vals[2:]]
    return pd.DataFrame({1: values[:N/2*len(x)], 2: values[N/2*len(x):]})

res = df.groupby(["Activity", "Iteration"]).apply(g).unstack()
r1 = res[1].T.rename(columns={(t,i):t+str(i)+"1" for t,i in res.index})
r2 = res[2].T.rename(columns={(t,i):t+str(i)+"2" for t,i in res.index})
res = pd.concat([r1,r2],axis=1).sort(axis=1)
res = res.rename(columns={t:t[:-2] for t in res.columns})

print df
print res
```

Which outputs:

```
   Activity  Iteration  col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D
0     test1          1      0      8      1      7
1     test1          1      2      0      5      0
2     test1          1      2      6      6      6
3     test1          1      5      0      1      4
4     test1          2      4      5      6      8
5     test1          2      8      0      1      6
6     test1          2      6      7      2      4
7     test1          2      3      2      2      3
8     test2          1      5      2      1      9
9     test2          1      8      3      5      9
10    test2          1      3      7      7      1
11    test2          1      7      4      5      1
12    test2          2      9      2      4      0
13    test2          2      3      1      8      7
14    test2          2      1      2      7      8
15    test2          2      4      9      7      0
   test1  test1  test1  test1  test2  test2  test2  test2
0      0      2      4      6      5      3      9      1
1      8      6      5      7      2      7      2      2
2      1      6      6      2      1      7      4      7
3      7      6      8      4      9      1      0      8
4      2      5      8      3      8      7      3      4
5      0      0      0      2      3      4      1      9
6      5      1      1      2      5      5      8      7
7      0      4      6      3      9      1      7      0
```

Hope it helps